# Using Get-ChildItem and copy-item to merge multiple files into 1 text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy the newest 3 files (by modified date) in a folder and then copy/merge those 3 files into 1 text file.

This is what i have tried. Its finding the last 3 files, but its only copying 1 file when i pipe to copy-item .. not copying/merging all 3 into 1 text file.

```
 get-childitem *.* | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3 | copy-item -destination last3files.txt
```

Would prefer a one liner if possible.

thank you

Comment: If you want to merge file contents, you need to add a step that reads the file contents and sets the file contents. `Get-Content | Set-Content`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge file contents, you need to add a step that reads the file contents and sets the file contents. `Get-Content | Set-Content`.

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object -Last 3 | Get-Content | Set-Content last3files.txt
```

`Copy-Item` will only copy items from the same namespace rather than the text contents of those items.

You may want to check out [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) and [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) for the `-Encoding` options just in case you have a mix of encodings across your files.